# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() when counting array length

Tags: excel, laravel

I am trying to styling border in laravel excel. But when i try to count some array length for dynamic border size, it returns an error message :

> "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()";

Here is my code:

```
public function registerEvents(): array
        {
            $aset = AsetBergerak::find($this->id_aset);
            $aset_view = ViewAset::find($this->id_aset);
            $today = Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('d F Y');
            $pengecekan = Pengecekan::where('id_aset_bergerak', $aset->id_aset_bergerak)->whereYear('waktu_cek', date('Y'))->get();
            $attraset = Pengecekan::where('id_aset_bergerak', $aset->id_aset_bergerak)->whereYear('waktu_cek', date('Y'))->first();
            foreach($pengecekan as $cek){
                $item =  PengecekanHasItem::where('id_pengecekan', $cek->id_pengecekan)->get();
                foreach($item as $konten){
                    $itemKonten[] = $konten;
                }
            }

            $row = count($itemKonten);
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: `$query->count()` returns an integer, what is there to iterate?

Comment: what "still didn't work"? what are you trying to do

Comment: there's some another mistake on my code, and your suggest make it works. thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i think you are getting the error in the inner loop. you need to check if `$item` is available.

```
public function registerEvents(): array
    {
        $aset = AsetBergerak::find($this->id_aset);
        $aset_view = ViewAset::find($this->id_aset);
        $today = Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('d F Y');
        $pengecekan = Pengecekan::where('id_aset_bergerak', $aset->id_aset_bergerak)->whereYear('waktu_cek', date('Y'))->get();
        $attraset = Pengecekan::where('id_aset_bergerak', $aset->id_aset_bergerak)->whereYear('waktu_cek', date('Y'))->first();
        $itemKonten = [];
        foreach($pengecekan as $cek){
            $item =  PengecekanHasItem::where('id_pengecekan', $cek->id_pengecekan)->get();
            if($item){
              foreach($item as $konten){
                $itemKonten[] = $konten;
              }
            }
        }

        $row = count($itemKonten);
```